# Bounded blocking queue

Tags: java, multithreading, interview-questions, queue

Can someone please review this code for me? I have not implemented all the methods for simplicity.

```
/**
 * Implements a blocking bounded queue from a given non-blocking unbounded queue implementation
 */
abstract class DerivedQueue<E> implements Queue<E>
{
    DerivedQueue(Queue<E> queue, int size)
    {
        if(queue==null | size <0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bad Input");
        }
        fQueue = queue;
        fSize = size;
    }



    Queue<E> fQueue;
    int fSize;
    int fCnt;

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> arg0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (fCnt==0);
    }

    public E remove()
    {
        if(fCnt==0)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Waiting thread was interrupted during remove with msg:",e);
            }
        }


        E elem =  fQueue.remove();
        fCnt--;
        notifyAll();
        return elem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E elem)
    {
        if(fCnt == fSize)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Waiting thread was interrupted during remove with msg:",e);
            }
        }

        return fQueue.add(elem);
    }

}
```

Open questions:

1. Would calling `notifyAll()` lead to multiple waiting threads checking the `while()` condition at the same time, and hence there is a possibility that before the while gets satisfied, 2 threads are already out of it causing an outOfBound exception? Or does the methods need to be marked `synchronized` at all, and instead I can use a `synchronized` block for reading or writing part of the array while the checking of constrained and waiting can remain unsynchronized?
2. Is there a way to notify precisely only the consumer threads (waiting in take) or only the producer (waiting input) threads in this example? `notifyAll` notifies all of them.

Comment: Logical OR is done using a double-pipe `||`. A single pipe `|` is for bitwise OR.

Answer (score 5):

This problem screams "[**semaphore**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)".

Have a semaphore whose count represents the number of slots available in the queue.  Enqueuers decrement the semaphore.  Dequeuers increment it.  This effectively caps the amount of nodes in the queue to some maximum, namely the initial value of the semaphore.

Likewise you can have a different semaphore represent the number of items currently enqueued.  In this case dequeuers decrement it and enqueuers increment.  For this one, the initial value is zero.  This allows dequeuers to block until an item is available.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is not threadsafe: Imagine the queue is empty, and several threads which want to remove an element are waiting. Then an element is added and **all** waiting threads are notified. Then they all try **without further tests** to remove an element, which will work only for the first thread, the next one will cause an underflow. Same scenario for several threads waiting to add.

So either fix the problem or add a comment with a "not threadsafe" warning.

Answer (score 2):

In my oppinion class variables should always be defined first - even before the constructor. Another issue: why are your variables prefixed with `f`? Rename to something less-confusing instead. Especially `fSize` and `fCnt` are quite close to each other. (Suggesting `maxSize` and `currentSize`).

Comment: thnx I have made some echanges, I use f to denote Class fields and distinguish them from local/method level fields

Comment: @p101 I use this. to use class fields ;) I know this is not required in java... but as you probably noticed - this doesn't increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

I could see two more issue with the above code:

1. These is missing increment to `fCurrrentCnt++` in the `add` method.
2. This will result in deadlock, if try to call `remove` first and then `add`. Both will wait for each other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement this yourself. [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) already is in the JRE. You can use [`ArrayBlockingQueue.take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) instead of the `remove` method and [`ArrayBlockingQueue.put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#put%28E%29) instead of the `add` method.

See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries*

Anyway, it does not seem completely thread-safe. The `fCurrrentCnt` field in the `isEmpty` method is read without any `synchronized` block.

> [...] synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

From *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*.